# Regarding group action on vN algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

$G$ be a discrete countable group acting on $M$ via automorphisms of $M$. Does there exist a faithful normal state on $M$ which preserves the action means $\varphi(\sigma_{g}(x))=\varphi(x)$, $\sigma:G\rightarrow Aut(M)$ is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false even in the Abelian. It is said that a Borel action of $G$ in a measure space $(X,\nu)$ (preserving the measure class) is of type $\mathrm{III}$ if there is no invariant semifinite measure $\mu$. You are asking for examples of type $\mathrm{III}$ actions.

**Edit:** If you want $\mu$ to be finite, then there are type $\mathrm{II}_\infty$ counterexamples. Let us take $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \subset SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ acting on $S^1 \cong SL_2(\mathbb{R}) / AN$, where $A$ are the diagonal matrices and $N$ is the nilpotent group
$$
  N = \Big\{ \Big( \begin{matrix} 1 & t\\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \Big) : t \in \mathrm{R} \Big\}.
$$
Basically, you are seeing $S^1$ as the $K$-part of the $KAN$ decomposition of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is nonamenable but the action is Zimmer amenable. If there were any invariant measures the group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ would be amenable. The same argument also gives (non-transitive) ergodic non-measure preserving actions when $\Gamma$, a hyperbolic group, acts on its Gromov boundary $\partial \Gamma$.

Comment: If $G$ is amenable is there any positive result?

Comment: Not if you persist both on normality and the state property. For example the canonical action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{Z})$ does not have an invariant normal state.

Comment: I didn't realize that you can also give type $\mathrm{I}$ counterexamples, like that. Basically any non-type II$_1$ would work.

Comment: But if $Aut(M)$ is amenable then it is always true!!

Comment: I can see how you would use an averaging argument in Aut$(M)$ but I doubt the result being normal.